# Self merging an object - lodash

Tags: javascript, list, object, lodash

I have one object:

```
obj1 = [{
           "accId": 23,
           "sName" : "qw" 
        }, 
        { 
           "accId": 23,
           "sName": "as" 
        },
        {
           "accId":24,
           "sName": "we"
        }
]
```

I want to use lodash to self merge this list of object into:

```
result = [{
             "accId": 23,
             "sName" : ["qw","as"]

          },
          {
           "accId":24,
           "sName": ["we"]
          }
]
```

I tried using pure javascript with for loops but it seems very inefficient. I also tried some lodash functions but could not find a perfect fit.
I have also thought of the idea of splitting the list of objects into separate lists with one object per list and merging using _.merge(). But I don't know if there is a way to split the list of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lodash you can use `_.flow()` to generate a function that starts by grouping items with the same `accId`, and then maps each group and generate a new object, with the collected `sName` values of the group:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, head } = _

const fn = flow(
  pr(groupBy, 'accId'),
  pr(map, vs => ({ ...head(vs), sName: map(vs, 'sName')}))
)

const array = [{"accId":23,"sName":"qw"},{"accId":23,"sName":"as"},{"accId":24,"sName":"we"}]

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea with Lodash/fp:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, head } = _

const fn = flow(
  groupBy('accId'),
  map(vs => ({ ...head(vs), sName: map('sName', vs)}))
)

const array = [{"accId":23,"sName":"qw"},{"accId":23,"sName":"as"},{"accId":24,"sName":"we"}]

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lodash [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) allows you to specify an iteratee which is passed each member of the array.  The resulting array will be unique with respect to the return values of that iteratee.

```js
let array = [{
    "accId": 23,
    "sName": "qw"
  },
  {
    "accId": 23,
    "sName": "as"
  },
  {
    "accId": 24,
    "sName": "we"
  }
]

let uniqArray = _.uniqBy(array, o => o.accId);
console.log(uniqArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you :) . But this does not give the output I desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom reduce function like this one:

```
function merge (data) {
  const values = data.reduce((acum, item) => {
    const key = item.accId
    let cached = acum[key]

    if (cached) {
      cached.sName.push(item.sName)
    } else {
      cached = {
        "accId": key,
        "sName": [item.sName]
      }
    }

    return { ...acum, [key]: cached }
  }, {})

  return Object.values(values)
}
```

This function will solve your problem.